# DPI Graphics Screen Resolution Pixels WinForm PrintPageEventArgs

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, printing, dpi

How do Dpi Points relate to Pixels for any display my application is running on?

```
int points;
Screen primary;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  points = -1;
  primary = null;
}

void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  if (points < 0) {
    points = (int)(e.Graphics.DpiX / 72.0F); // There are 72 points per inch
  }
  if (primary == null) {
    primary = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
    Console.WriteLine(primary.WorkingArea.Height);
    Console.WriteLine(primary.WorkingArea.Width);
    Console.WriteLine(primary.BitsPerPixel);
  }
}
```

Do I now have all of the information I need?

Can I use any of the information above to find out just how long 1200 pixels is?

Comment: Note: Once I learn how to display my Form universally, the data on that form will be sent to a printer - hence the `PrintPageEventArgs` in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize it has been a few months, but while reading a book on WPF, I came across the answer:

If using standard Windows DPI setting (96 dpi), each device-independent unit corresponds to one real, physical pixel.

```
[Physical Unit Size] = [Device-Independent Unit Size] x [System DPI]
                     = 1/96 inch x 96 dpi
                     = 1 pixel
```

Hence, 96 pixels to make an inch through the Windows system DPI settings.

However, this does, in reality, depend on your display size.

For a 19-inch LDC monitor set to a resolution of 1600 x 1200, use the Pythagoras theorem helps to calculate pixel density for the monitor:

```
[Screen DPI] = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(1600, 2) + Math.Pow(1200, 2)) / 19
```

Using this data, I wrote up a little static tool that I now keep in my Tools class of all my projects:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the Screen Dots Per Inch of a Display Monitor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="monitorSize">Size, in inches</param>
/// <param name="resolutionWidth">width resolution, in pixels</param>
/// <param name="resolutionHeight">height resolution, in pixels</param>
/// <returns>double presision value indicating the Screen Dots Per Inch</returns>
public static double ScreenDPI(int monitorSize, int resolutionWidth, int resolutionHeight) {
  //int resolutionWidth = 1600;
  //int resolutionHeight = 1200;
  //int monitorSize = 19;
  if (0 < monitorSize) {
    double screenDpi = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(resolutionWidth, 2) + Math.Pow(resolutionHeight, 2)) / monitorSize;
    return screenDpi;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I hope others get some use out of this nifty little tool.

Answer (score 3):

DPI literally stands for "Dots Per Inch" - where dots==pixels.  So to determine how long 1200 pixels is:

```
int inchesLong = (1200 / e.Graphics.DpiX);
```

Comment: Video dpi settings are never accurate.  They are fixed to 96 or 120 or 144 regardless of the monitor size.

Comment: @Hans Not true. I've test my app at 192DPI, for example. It does look pretty funky, but it scales alright!

Comment: @David - did you buy another monitor to match that dpi setting?  Required to get the inch measurement the same.

Comment: @Hans I manifested my app to be DPIAWARE and then I thought I ought to at least stress it some! Sadly you can't buy panels with enough pixels to make that DPI setting viable, but it would look great if you could. And I'm ready for it!!

Answer (score 1):

For the screen: pixels = Graphics.DpiY * points / 72

For the printer, mentioned in your question subject, mapping is 1 'pixel' == 0.010 inches by default.  This is quite close to the default video dpi of 96 dots per inch making the copy on paper about the same size as what you see on the monitor.

Making screen shots of your form and printing them is a bad idea.  Printers have much higher resolutions, 600 dpi is typical.  The printout will look grainy as each pixel on the screen becomes a 6x6 blob on paper.  Especially noticeable and fugly for anti-aliased text.

Comment: Actually, the form is just to present a 'print preview' of the data before sending it to the printer. The project should draw all of the data to a form as it will be sent to the printer. Clear as mud? :)

Comment: But, which came first, the Chicken or the Egg? LOL - I've got to paint the object to SOMETHING before I can use MS's PrintPreviewDialog ...unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Erm, you ultimately want to print it.  Once you got that, you get the preview for free.  Doing it the other way around is a waste of time.  Implement the PrintDocument.PrintPage event handler.

Comment: ...well, in that case, I'd have to create a custom PrintPreview. My current paint event is going to send info a panel on the form. There will also be Add and Remove buttons to include more 'objects' to the list to print.

Comment: You paint to a Device Context (System.Drawing.Graphics). In a Paint handler or OnPaint override, the DC was obtained by a call to BeginPaint and is a "screen DC". When you print, you are supplied a "print DC". When using the PrintDialog or PrintPreviewDialog, you provide a PrintDocument object. It is in the PrintPage event of that document that you obtain a "print DC" to paint to.