# Getting wrong screen resolution from Screen Class

Tags: c#, .net, screen, screen-resolution

I was building some tools for my daily job.
I tried use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/Width` to get system resolution
But if system is set to a "none small" DPI setting, c# will reply wrong resolution
For example: When my DPI is set as small, I can get real resolution as 1920x1080.
But the resolution become 1536x864 with Middle DPI setting and 1280x720 with Large DPI setting

Looks like c# will only get Virtual Resolution from system via Screen class.

**Is there any other way to get "Real" display resolution?**
I tried `SystemInformation`, it get same result

Comment: try this answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122050/dpi-graphics-screen-resolution-pixels-winform-printpageeventargs

Comment: Thank you KCdod, but this solution is using to get system DPI. Not real display resolution.

Answer (score 0):

in WPF application, You can try any of the following properties to find out which one fit your task the best:

```
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight

SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth
SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight

SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width
SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: this may work, however I think he was saying that with different DPI resolutions these API calls aren't working correctly for him.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but VP is right. SystemParameters will only get virtual resolution too... I tried use Win32_DesktopMonitor, but it hard to use in my case...